# Values for custom select attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, category, multiselect-attribute, category-attribute

I am adding multiselect custom attribute to Catalog.
/app/code/local/MyPlugins/Category/sql/category_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'label' => 'Blog Category', 
    'type' => 'varchar', 
    'input' => 'multiselect', 
    'backend' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array', 
    'frontend' => '', 
    'source' => '', 
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL, 
    'visible' => true, 
    'required' => false, 
    'user_defined' => false, 
    'searchable' => false, 
    'filterable' => false, 
    'comparable' => false, 
    'option' => array(
        'value' => array(
            'optionone' => array('First Option'), 
            'optiontwo' => array('Second Option'), 
            'optionthree' => array('Third Option'),)), 
    'visible_on_front' => false, 
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false, 
    'unique' => false
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'blog_category', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

How can I change this options after creating attribute?

```
'option' => array(
    'value' => array(
        'optionone' => array('First Option'), 
        'optiontwo' => array('Second Option'), 
        'optionthree' => array('Third Option'),)),
```

I'm using magento 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttributeOption` for adding, updating and deleting attribute options.

From the implementation of this function you can deduce the format of `$options` array.